# Get around using a view with SQL queries

Tags: sql

I have the following query :

```
Create View Temp2 as 
(SELECT CurrentLoan.memberID, bookID, due_date 
 FROM CurrentLoan, Member
 WHERE CurrentLoan.memberID = Member.memberID 
 AND Member.firstname ="John" 
 AND Member.lastname = "Smith");

SELECT Temp2.bookID, Book.title, Temp2.due_date 
FROM Temp2, Book 
WHERE Temp2.bookID = Book.bookID ;
```

However, I need to be able to generate the same result without using any views and all in one statement. Any suggestions to how to get this set up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `JOIN`. I'm assuming that `bookID` comes from `CurrentLoan`

```
SELECT CurrentLoan.bookID, Book.title, CurrentLoan.due_date
FROM CurrentLoan
JOIN Member ON CurrentLoan.memberID = Member.memberID
JOIN Book ON CurrentLoan.bookID = Book.bookID 
WHERE Member.firstname ="John" AND Member.lastname = "Smith"
```

Comment: Write the join as it is. LEFT or INNER. Dont write JOIN, its bad pratice

Comment: @plaidDK could you please post a reference? thank you. One more question: why JOIN need INNER whereas LEFT JOIN does not need OUTER according to the good practice?

Comment: @plaidDK for example, I can find articles (https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-code-smells/#using-the-old-sybase-join-syntax) describing SQL code smell using old join syntax (without join), however, I have never seen a serious recommendation that you suggest.

Comment: Because RIGHT OUTER and LEFT OUTER is the same as LEFT or RIGHT JOIN. However, a normal JOIN can be misinterpert by users cause they do not know what in fact it does. Even though its a INNER JOIN. Therefore WRITE Inner join when it is a inner join. And write left or right join

Comment: Ambiguity is bad in all code.  Using `INNER JOIN`, `LEFT JOIN`, `RIGHT JOIN` and `CROSS JOIN` is explicit.  Not only is it easier to read, it makes it clear that you specifically chose that join, as opposed to possibly failing to understand that different joins exist.  That said, the most important conventions and standards are the ones that are actually in use in the environment being coded in.

Comment: Also if you have multiple other joins eg. left joins users might tend to think that a join is the same. Therefore be specific when you write your joins. (Its just an advice)

Comment: @plaidDK There is no DBMS processing `JOIN` as an `OUTER JOIN`, therefore, I believe that there is no room for misinterpretation unless you do not know the SQL and in such case then `INNER` keyword will not help you. You are suggesting a certain style of SQL code writing which I accept. Everyone has its style, however, I would not consider it as a bad practice.

Comment: @RadimBača Thats up to you. I would consider it bad practice. I know what it stands for, but many others dont.